# Is a relation transitieve if and only if $R\circ R \subset R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y, Z$ be sets and call $R\subset X\times Y$ a relation from $X$ to $Y$. Let $R$ be a relation from $X$ to $Y$ and S a relation from $Y$ to $Z$. Then composition relation is given by $S\circ R=\{(x,z)\in X\times Z: \text{there is a } y\in $Y$ \text{ such that }(xRy \text{ and } ySz)$.

I wonder whether a relation $R$ is transitive if and only if $R\circ R \subset R$.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should say $S\circ R=\{(x,z)\in X\times Z: \text{there is a } y\in $Y$ \text{ such that }(xRy \text{ and } ySz)$ instead of $S\circ R=\{(x,z)\in X\times Z: \text{there is a } y\in $Y$ \text{ such that }(xRy \text{ and } yRz)$.

Notice the change. And yes then your statement is true.